# Proving the formula by induction on n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction

I am having problems with proving the following formula by using induction.

$${r \choose r} + {r+1 \choose r} + {r+2 \choose r} + ... + {n \choose r} = {n+1 \choose r+1}$$

It is stated in the question that the r is arbitrary but fixed, which I also don't understand.
If anyone could guide my how to solve this I would be very grateful.

Comment: This is called the [hockey-stick identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1).

Comment: But what does r is arbitrary but fixed mean can some one explain

Comment: @Djboboch, "$r$ is arbitrary but fixed" means, in this case, that while $r$ is some arbitrary number, you consider only one $r$ for the entire proof; unlike $n$, over which you try to do induction. That is: fix $r$. Then consider the base case, namely $n = r$; then the equation states $\binom rr = \binom{r+1}{r+1}$, which is true. Now suppose that the equation is true for $n$; then prove it for $n + 1$.

Comment: Observes   that ${j \choose r} = 0~~~j<r$ and this [This ][1]    [1]:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1

Comment: In my opinion, "$r$ is fixed" is irrelevant for the statement of the identity itself, but it's essential for the _proof_.

Comment: See alsp (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/972368)